# Javascript how to filter object array contains exact word

Tags: javascript

How do I filter the word "mango" in an array from an object that contains, please? Example "mango"

```
var myIteams= [
  {   
    title: "Title One",
    section: 1,
    tag: ["orange", "apple", "banana", "mango"]
  },
  {   
    title: "Title Two",
    section: 15,
    tag: ["mango"]
  },
  {   
    title: "Title Three",
    section: 21,
    tag: ["orange", "apple" ]
  },

]
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Have you tried anything? What was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Array.prototype.filter` to filter the array with callback. Then use `Array.prototype.includes` to match the right item.

```js
var myItems = [
  {   
    title: "Title One",
    section: 1,
    tag: ["orange", "apple", "banana", "mango"]
  },
  {   
    title: "Title Two",
    section: 15,
    tag: ["mango"]
  },
  {   
    title: "Title Three",
    section: 21,
    tag: ["orange", "apple" ]
  },

];

const match = myItems.filter(item => {
  return item.tag.includes('mango');
});
console.log(match);
```

Comment: got it perfect. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for this. It takes a function which should return something either 'truthy' or 'falsey'. If it returns something truthy, it keeps the item, otherwise it is filtered out.

```js
var myIteams= [
  {   
    title: "Title One",
    section: 1,
    tag: ["orange", "apple", "banana", "mango"]
  },
  {   
    title: "Title Two",
    section: 15,
    tag: ["mango"]
  },
  {   
    title: "Title Three",
    section: 21,
    tag: ["orange", "apple" ]
  },

]

const result = myIteams.filter(item => item.tag.indexOf('mango') > -1)

console.dir(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` to filter the array and `some` to find a tag list, which contains your desired value.

```js
var myItems = [{
    title: "Title One",
    section: 1,
    tag: ["orange", "apple", "banana", "mango"]
  },
  {
    title: "Title Two",
    section: 15,
    tag: ["mango"]
  },
  {
    title: "Title Three",
    section: 21,
    tag: ["orange", "apple"]
  },

]


const filtered = myItems.filter(o => o.tag.some(t => t === 'mango'));
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to get elements which contains tag '*Mango*' in it

> Filter: Filter provides new array where we get elements from existing
>   array with some condition.
>
> includes: It is used to determines wheter array includes certain
>   element or not. It returns `true` or `false`

```js
var myIteams= [
  {   
    title: "Title One",
    section: 1,
    tag: ["orange", "apple", "banana", "mango"]
  },
  {   
    title: "Title Two",
    section: 15,
    tag: ["mango"]
  },
  {   
    title: "Title Three",
    section: 21,
    tag: ["orange", "apple" ]
  },

];

var result = myIteams.filter(x => x.tag.includes("mango"));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filter method with an includes method in it. Here's an example of creating a function that lets you pass in what item you want to find.

```
var myItems = [
  {   
    title: "Title One",
    section: 1,
    tag: ["orange", "apple", "banana", "mango"]
  },
  {   
    title: "Title Two",
    section: 15,
    tag: ["mango"]
  },
  {   
    title: "Title Three",
    section: 21,
    tag: ["orange", "apple" ]
  },
];

function findItem(itemToFind) {
  return myItems.filter(item => item.tag.includes(itemToFind));
}

console.log(findItem('mango'))
```